# VueJs2 Autocomplete imported but not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a small web project in Laravel+VueJs and now I'm migrating it from VueJs 1.x to 2. Everything was good with the vue-migration-helper but my problem is with the vuejsautocomplete component. I googled that for VueJs2 there's a vuejs2autocomplete library based on vuejsautocomplete so I imported it, then used it but mi autocomplete inputs didn't work properly.

Here's my Vue object

```js
        var cadApp = new Vue({
            el: '#cadContainer',
            data: {
                inputPrestadorEfector: '',
                frmAfiliado: {
                    inputNumeroAfiliado: '',
                    inputDocumentoAfiliado: '',
                    inputTipoDocumentoAfiliado: '',
                },
                dataAfiliado: {
                    msje:'',
                    contextualClass:'',
                    idUnico:'',
                },//resultado de la consulta
                //prestaciones
                frmPrestaciones : {
                    inputPrestacionCodigo :'',
                    inputPrestacionDescripcion :'',
                },
                dataPrestacion: {
                    msje:'',//no viene en la consulta
                },//resultado de la consulta
                dataPrestaciones: {!! json_encode(old('dataPrestaciones') ?: []) !!},//lista de prestaciones consultadas
                //solicitudes
                frmSolicitud:{

                },
                dataSolicitud: {!! json_encode(old('dataSolicitud') ?: ['idSolicitud'=>0, 'msje'=>'', 'contextualClass'=>'']) !!},
//                {
//                    idSolicitud:0,//0 indica que la solicitud no fue creada
//                    msje:'',
//                    contextualClass:'',
//                },//resultado de la consulta
                solicitudes: [],
                loading: false,
                error: false,
                query: ''
            },
            components: {
                autocomplete: Vue2Autocomplete
            },
            methods: {
......
......
```

And here's how i used the autocomplete component (at least with the first version it worked)

```html
<div class="input-group-addon">Código:</div>
                        <autocomplete
                                class="form-control"
                                name="inputPrestacionCodigo"
                                placeholder="Código práctica"
                                url="prestacion/codigo"
                                param="CODIGO_PRESTACION"
                                min="2"
                                max="9"
                                limit="50"
                                anchor="CODIGO_PRESTACION"
                                model="frmPrestaciones.inputPrestacionCodigo">
                        </autocomplete>
```

Vuedevtools recognizes both autocomplete components but in browser console i get:

```js
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

found in

---> <Autocomplete>
       <Root>
```

Comment: Please don't post so many lines of code, only the portion that is important.
Nobody will look at it elseway. :)

Comment: And you might have to tell us what exactly doesn't work. Any errors?

Comment: Post updated...

Answer (score 0):

Finally after some research i've found the solution.
Adding default to the component registration fixed the problem:

```
components: {
            autocomplete: Vue2Autocomplete.default
        },
```

Hope it can help others too.